# Cross side scripting user name validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, devextreme

I am working on a java script based application where I need to validate the username text box then what are all the symbols I should avoid in order to block cross side scripting using **REGEX**

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just a username you should maybe accept only alphanumeric chars, something like:
`~^[a-z0-9_.-]+$~i`

[EDIT] to add explanations:

- `~`: delimiter but in JS you will need `/` to delimit instead
- `i`: case insensitive flag
- `^`: match beginning of string
- `$`: match end of string
- `[]`: match characters in between those brackets
- `a-z`: is a to z range
- `0-9`: 0 to 9 range
- `_.-`: also accepts those chars
- `+`: is to allow this pattern 1 or more times